# Q: Stop Puppet from gathering notifies

Tags: puppet, notify

I have the two puppet codes below:

x.pp

```
    class x (
Hash $something = undef,  
)
{ 
  if ($something) {
    create_resources("profile::aem::install_packages", $sources, $defaults)
  }
}
```

y.pp

```
    define x::y( 
  String  $xx = undef,  
)
{
   file { "$name" :
    ensure      => $ensure,
    ....
    } ~>

    service['some-service']
}
```

The 'y' define, is called 3 times by the 'x' class because of the $something variable which is a hash. The goal of my notify is to restart a service after the file/package is present. However because of puppets behaviour, it accumulates all the notifys and restarts the service only once, but in my case I need it to restart the service after every change that is occuring. Is there any way to stop puppets behaviour of accumulating notifies and restart the service for example 3 times instead of 1?

Thank you so much for your time.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 3):

Puppet is about writing out a Declarative state that your system should be in, not an Imperative 'do this then that'..

The nature of this is describe in this blog post by Ben Ford - https://puppet.com/blog/puppet%E2%80%99s-declarative-language-modeling-instead-of-scripting

There isn't a good way to put multiple 'service restarts' of the same service in a single puppet run, since puppet's model is to manage each resource signally, and collect notifications.

There may be some way around it by specifying a different service resource title, while specifying the actual service to manage in a different parameter, but I would not recommend it.

There seems to be a similar answer given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11107074/3543867

Comment: Thank you for @cinderhaze :)